# Focus event does not bubble up to the parent in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Please take a look at the following code;

```js
const wrapper = document.getElementById("wrapper");
wrapper.tabIndex = 0;
wrapper.onfocus = e => {
    console.log("focus event triggered");
}
wrapper.oncontextmenu = e => {
    console.log("context menu event triggered");
}
Highcharts.chart('container', {

    title: {
        text: 'Focus'
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Foo', 'Bar', 'Foobar'],
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4]
    }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="wrapper" style="height: 400px; width: 500px">
    <div id="container" style="height: 400px; width: 500px"></div>
</div>
```

Focus event does not happen when clicking on the chart. However if I right click on the chart to show the context menu, focus event happens. Could you please help me how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is related with this issue: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/11824

And it is caused by calling `e.preventDefault` in `onContainerMouseDown` method: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/blob/61419f1d60b0e0fb069569e23e609e12b1943ea5/ts/Core/Pointer.ts#L1232

As a workaround add the below plugin:

```
(function(H) {
    H.wrap(H.Pointer.prototype, 'onContainerMouseDown', function(proceed) {
        proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        document.getElementById("wrapper").focus();
    });
}(Highcharts));
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/L08nagq4/

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts